# Is there a grace period for getting money back out of your 401k plan?

Tags: united-states, 401k, withdrawal, penalty

Is there a "grace period" on getting that money back out? For example, if I put $3000 in in April, and I need that $3000 in May, can get it out before the end of the year, can I just pay the "regular tax" on it for the year, or do I have to pay the penalty as well?

Comment: But “you” don’t put $3000 into a 401k in March.  **Your employer** puts a fraction of your wages into your 401k account.  That might sound pedantic, but it’s a major difference between a 401k and IRA.

Comment: If you need money, either borrow from your 401k, or stop contributing.  Of course, the proper tactic is to use money from your Emergency Fund.

Comment: @RonJohn "the proper tactic" well, it might well be tax-favorable to get paid this year rather than 30 years from now.  It is entirely possible to prefer to pay the taxes this year, but to have not known this fact until May.

Comment: As I understand it, borrowing from the 401k is often not better than borrowing from the bank. "Paying yourself the interest" may not be enough to make up for losing the tax advantaged growth. Run the numbers before taking that option. The folks who manage your 401k may have tools to help you estimate this.

Comment: @keshlam its not necessarily tax advantaged.  It's only tax advantaged depending on how much I make during the year, and how much I make during the year isn't necessarily known to me at the beginning of the year.  What happened last year is I put money into my 401k, then my employment situation changed in such a way that my tax bracket was very low.  I will probably actually be tax *disadvantaged* on the 401k funds, because when I end up withdrawing them, I'll be in a higher bracket.

Comment: @keshlam what I would like in a perfect world is not to borrow from my 401k, but to change my mind about having made such a large contribution at the beginning of the year.  I would have to pay taxes on it, but those taxes would be very little.  What I don't want to do is to have to pay the penalty, because that is actually more than the interest on a loan.  Hence my hope that there was a grace period on retirement deposits.

Comment: @keshlam "you probably" what? I know I didn't put any money in after April *because I wasn't employed there anymore*  I can't change the amount being deducted now *because I don't get a paycheck*

Comment: Maximum possible 401k deduction for this year is $22,500 (maybe plus company match; I'm not sure). So if you maxed out,  your April contribution would have been $1875. Unless the company is giving you a high matching payment, I'm not sure how you get to $3000. Apologies if I'm quibbling with a number intended only as an example rather than as a real case.

Comment: @keshlam well, it's neither April nor May, so you should take this as an example.  Either way, I'm allowed to change my contribution per month.  My April contribution last year was actually *more* than $3000 if you are actually interested.

Comment: @keshlam but yes, I did intend this as an example.  If you know how one might make this example into something that people in less odd circumstances might reasonably experience, but that preserves the spirit of the question, I encourage you to edit it.

Comment: OK, I'm now clear on what's being asked... There is no grace period that I know of, but I'd be glad to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For a 401(k), probably not, since most 401(k) contributions also have an employer match, and the deduction for the contribution is baked into your paycheck for that period.  Otherwise you could "game" the system by contributing the max, getting a match, and pulling it back out.

For an IRA, yes, but you also need to withdraw any earnings (or reduce the withdrawal if there is a loss) associated with that contribution. You can do that up to the filing deadline for the tax year (e.g. April 15, 2024 for a withdrawal of a contribution made in 2023).

Any time you're dealing with retirement accounts and significant tax consequences, talk to your IRA provider, broker, or a local tax professional. There may be specifics to your circumstances that don't apply to the situation in general. You will probably need your broker's help to determine if any gains or losses need to be included in the reversal as well.

Comment: mmm.. My 401k plan doesn't have a match.  My employer puts in $x no matter what I do, and I can choose to put more in on top of it.

Comment: @Him have you tried asking HR or your plan administrator?

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD No.  It didn't really occur to me to even attempt this last year, when it would have made sense.  Unfortunately, it's not May anymore.  :D  However, I'm still curious, and maybe someone else will benefit from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a "grace period" on getting that money back out?

Maybe. It depends on the options available with your 401(k) plan.

Back before there were Roth accounts you had the option of putting in the money pre-tax or post-tax. The company match and the growth was always pre-tax. But if you specified your contributions as post-tax you could pull the money out at any time. My office mate did this. He contributed 8%, the company contributed 8%, and every quarter he submitted paperwork (this was the 1980's) to pull his contributions from the plan. The company contribution continued to grow.

A 401(k) can still allow post-tax non-Roth contributions. They can even allow you to pull out the contributions. You can even roll these contributions into a Roth.

Check your company plan documents.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your core concern is about tax brackets.  There's an easy way to save this.  Maybe.

If you are in a low tax bracket *right now*, and your employer 401(K) permits Roth, then it may be very useful to **convert to Roth** within the 401(K).

With Roth, you pay the tax when you contribute or convert, (so whatever amount you convert becomes taxable income this year).  And then you never pay tax again on the principal or appreciation on the Roth part.  Also, on Roth there will be no mandatory withdrawals at age 73 like a traditional.

The mathemagicians will tell you that it's a wash, and the presumably lower tax bracket in retirement favors the traditional. *But they haven't spent much time around assisted living and skilled nursing facilities*.  People needing endlife care blow through their savings at astonishing speed, and that can put them into the highest tax brackets of their entire lives if they haven't already converted to Roth.   So if you can, I advise taking advantage of gap years by converting all you can to Roth.

Comment: RMD age was raised to 72 several years ago, and is going up to 73 this year; Roth 401k (unlike IRA) _does_ have RMDs right now, but that will go away _next_ year (and someone making deferrals/contributions this year is probably not 73 already). Otherwise concur.